# Meta Trader 5 - How to get no of decimals of current market

Tags: metatrader5

I'm fairly new to Meta Trader 5.  I would like to know how I can determine the number of digits behind the decimal point for a market for the price calculation.

Example:
The DAX is traded as of 1 point. There is also a decimal place, but if I put, for example, one euro per point, I receive 1 euro when the DAX rises from 15000 to 15001.

With gold it is different. There I also have a decimal place. Here, however, the point is fixed at 0.1, i.e. if I put one euro per point, I get 10 € when the gold price rises from 2000 to 2001.

I already found out that there are some infos, but currently not what I need:

```
#include <Trade/PositionInfo.mqh>

CSymbolInfo symbolInfo;
SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_POINT); //DAX = 0.1 - Why?
SymbolInfoDouble(_Symbol,SYMBOL_VOLUME_STEP);
symbolInfo.Digits(); //0.0 always - Why?
...
```

and so on. But no one of these provided me the market information I need. I mean

> DAX = 1
>
> Gold = 0.1
>
> Forex = 0.0001
>
> ...

So how do I get this information out of the Meta Trader system?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options in MQL5.

You can get the number of digits for the current chart symbol using

[int Digits();](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/check/digits)

Or you can get the digits for any chart using

[long  SymbolInfoInteger(symbol, SYMBOL_DIGITS);](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/marketinformation/symbolinfointeger)